# Unsuccessful migration of my_worspace from GeoServer 15.2 to GeoServer 16.0

Tags: geoserver, workspace, migration

What I have to do for migration of my workspace from one GeoServer to another (from 15.2 on server#1 to 16.2 on server#2)?
What I do:
-replace directory `tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/my_workspace_dir`
-restarted tomcat.
What I have had? this:
-have had workspace in GUI geoserver
-have had styles in GUI geoserver (but all are broken, when I opened them,
they throw this: `org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleEditPage(org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters)' ...`
- no one source (DB) or layers from my workspace

What I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move a single worskspace around by simple file copies, the unit that can be moved is the data directory.

You may want to try the backup/restore plugin, but mind, it's an unsupported community module, not sure it it will work or not: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/backuprestore/usagegui.html

Comment: so I have  to replace a "clean" data directory from new geoserver (server#2) by data directory with my_workspace from "old" directory (from server#1)?

Comment: Exactly. A copy of it preferably, keep a backup of it.